# how to make dropdown content with nav-tabs in bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i'm using bootstrap nav-tabs(vertical pills). i want to make this - when i click on tab, the content of THIS tab drop downing exactly under this tab(not somewhere else) like [this](http://gsservices.ge/index.php?task=public.Home&id=3&lang=eng&class_id=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then the Bootstrap feature what you are looking for is called **Accordion** or **Collapse** and not Nav-Tabs.

Here is the link where its available in the bootstrap documentation. You do not need any extra plugin except ofcourse `jquery.min.js'`, `bootstrap.js` and  `bootstrap.css` to make this work.

**Important Note** : *`jquery.min.js` should be loaded before `bootstrap.js`.*

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Here is the basic [Accordion example](https://jsfiddle.net/tuvc5c7w/1/) with the required libraries.

Hope it helped :-)

Comment: thank you for reply! i have already found solution.i think  in this situation its better to use bootstrap accordion:  [accordion] (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion) anyway, thank you!

Comment: What i mentioned leads to the same link :-) Glad you found the answer. Now you could mark this as correct and close this question.

Answer (score 0):

From [the Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav):

> Navs available in Bootstrap have shared markup, starting with the base `.nav` class, as well as shared states. Swap modifier classes to switch between each style.
>
> #### Using navs for tab panels requires JavaScript tabs plugin
>
> For tabs with tabbable areas, you must use the tabs JavaScript plugin. The markup will also require additional `role` and ARIA attributes – see the plugin's example markup for further details.
>
> #### Make navs used as navigation accessible
>
> If you are using navs to provide a navigation bar, be sure to add a `role="navigation"` to the most logical parent container of the `<ul>`, or wrap a `<nav>` element around the whole navigation. Do not add the role to the `<ul>` itself, as this would prevent it from being announced as an actual list by assistive technologies.

Comment: thanks for replying. can you please, tell which plugin i should use? (cannot find it in documentation)

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution. if someone also have this problem, just check bootstrap accordion

[accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion)

thats it!